# referencing custom javascript file in node.js web app

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I am learning node.js and am starting with the common chat app example. I got everything working fine but instead of doing all the javascript inline in the index.html file, I want to put it in it's own file called app.js. However, once I do this, I get 404 not found on the file. I'm trying to play around with the src path but can't get it to find the file. Is there a trick to referencing custom js/css files when it's a node app?

**Index.html**

```
<div id="chat"></div>
<form id="send-message">
    <input type="text" id="message" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="/app.js"></script>
<script>

</script>
```

**server.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
var path = require('path');
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'app.js')));
server.listen(process.env.port || 3000);

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

    socket.on('send message', function (message) {
        console.log(message);
        io.sockets.emit('new message', message);
    });
});
```

**app.js**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var socket = io.connect();
    var form = $('#send-message');
    var message = $('#message');
    var chat = $('#chat');

    form.submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        socket.emit('send message', message.val());
        message.val('');
    });

    socket.on('new message', function (data) {
        chat.append(data + "<br />");
    });

});
```

I may get hung up on grasping the concept of node but I'm assuming I shouldn't have to do anything within the actual server.js itself since that is the server side code and I shouldn't be doing any dom manipulation within the server side. Adding the custom js file like you normally would with a standard web app doesn't seem to be the correct way here. I've noticed that in almost all of the tutorials/documentation i've seen/read, they are referencing libraries such as jquery and bootstrap by calling the cdn url rather than including those files as a module or in a local directory. Just based on this and the 404 errors I continue to get, I'm assuming there is a different way to include external js references to local files within the web app.

[image: F12 Developer Tools]

[image: File structure]

Fiddler output:

```
GET http://localhost:1337/app.js HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:1337
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36
Accept: */*
Referer: http://localhost:1337/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: __utma=111872281.1352628776.1455330937.1455330937.1455330937.1; __utmz=111872281.1455330937.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `express.static()` in your `server.js`. You're not establishing static assets in your Express server so you can't serve files.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

server.listen(process.env.port || 3000);

// The below works but isn't a good practice because it's not scalable
app.use('/app.js', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/app.js')));

// You should create a public directory in your project folder and
// place all your static files there and the below app.use() will
// serve all files and sub-directories contained within it.
//app.use('public', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});
```

Typically you don't set a file as static like I did in the above snippet. You'd establish a static directory, such as `public` then within your public directory you can place your static assets(CSS, JS, HTML) that can be served.

Comment: ok. I'm fiddling with this. I saw this posted somewhere else as well but don't understand why I need to include this within the server side. I'll figure that part out later. However, I am getting `path is undefined.` Where is that `path` variable defined or what should it be set to?

Comment: `path` is a Node Core module. You can just require it. See my updated answer.

Comment: OK. thanks. I'm still getting the 404 error, however. I have included the updated code to server.js

Comment: `path.join(__dirname, '/app.js')` outputs the correct path to the file i'm after....

Comment: Still getting 404 errors. Appreciating your help though!

Comment: @mwilson The answer has been updated, i've confirmed this works locally for me. I do advise you to change this and place it into a different directory like public and serve your assets from there though so you don't need to write a `app.use()` for each new file you want to serve as a script in your HTML.

Comment: there we go! i agree with creating the public folder. I would rather have that anyways but this is just a fiddle for now. Last question: What is the reason why I need to tell server.js about the location of my static assets? I would have thought once the html page was loaded, it would load up the rest of my files (like it's doing with jquery). Is this an express requirement or node requirement? (or both). Seems kind of redundant to have to define the location of your files in two places....

Comment: Your jQuery is being loaded from a remote host, if you actually hosted it within node, you'd also need to set it as a static file. The reason for this is simply because Express doesn't know about the files and you need to instruct Express when to serve the files, and which files are static.